# rx.js catchup subscription from two sources

Tags: arrays, node.js, functional-programming, rxjs

I need to combine a catch up and a subscribe to new feed.  So first I query the database for all new records I've missed, then switch to a pub sub for all new records that are coming in.

The first part is easy  do your query, perhaps in batches of 500, that will give you an array and you can rx.observeFrom that.

The second part is easy you just put an rx.observe on the pubsub.

But I need to do is sequentially so I need to play all the old records before I start playing the new ones coming in.

I figure I can start the subscribe to pubsub, put those in an array, then start processing the old ones, and when I'm done either remove the dups ( or since I do a dup check ) allow the few dups, but play the accumulated records until they are gone and then one in one out.

my question is what is the best way to do this?  should I create a subscribe to start building up new records in an array, then start processing old, then in the "then" of the oldrecord process subscribe to the other array?

Ok this is what I have so far.  I need to build up the tests and finish up some psudo code to find out if it even works, much less is a good implementation.  Feel free to stop me in my tracks before I bury myself.

```
var catchUpSubscription = function catchUpSubscription(startFrom) {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
    var subscription = this.getCurrentEventsSubscription();
    // calling map to start subscription and catch in an array.  
    // not sure if this is right
    var events = rx.Observable.fromEvent(subscription, 'event').map(x=> x);
    // getPastEvents gets batches of 500 iterates over and emits each 
   // till no more are returned, then resolves a promise
    this.getPastEvents({count:500, start:startFrom})
    .then(function(){
        rx.Observable.fromArray(events).forEach(x=> emit('event', x));
    });
};
```

I don't know that this is the best way.  Any thoughts?

thx

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid mixing your different async strategies unnecessarily. You can use `concat` to join together the two sequences:

```
var catchUpSubscription = function catchUpSubscription(startFrom) {
    var subscription = this.getCurrentEventsSubscription();

    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(this.getPastEvents({count:500, start:startFrom}))
     .flatMap(x => x)
     .concat(Rx.Observable.fromEvent(subscription, 'event'));

};

///Sometime later
catchUpSubscription(startTime).subscribe(x => /*handle event*/)
```

Comment: Ah, nice this is what i was looking for. Couple questions.  The getpastevents, that loops till there are no more events.  I need to look at the result of the db query to see if there was anything returned.  I guess im not sure how to manage that if im returning promises.  Secondly, am i racking up new events from the time i create the subscription or only after i subscribe to it? I cant risk missing an event between the catching up and reading live .

Comment: Now that i think about it, the first part is no good because itll keep picking up new events. Crap.